# Socket IO with multiple tabs not working and when refreshing the page

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'am using socket.io to make tracking location & alerts but when i open more than one tab the socket work only with the new tab
I created some pages to test the socket and when i open one page it's working good but when i opened another page the socket worked good with the new page and stopped working in the old page.

**The socket server code**

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socket = require('socket.io');
require('custom-env').env('nodejs');

const SocketServer = require('./socket');

//===================================================================
class Server {
   constructor() {
       this.port = process.env.NODEJS_PORT;
       this.host = process.env.NODEJS_HOST;

       this.app = express();
       this.router = express.Router();
       this.http = http.Server(this.app); // Node js Server
       this.socket = socket(this.http); // Here Run A Socket io Module
   }

   runServer() {
       new SocketServer(this.socket).SocketConnection(); // This Is Socket Class

       // Listening A Node Js Server
       this.http.listen(this.port, this.host, () => {
           console.log(`Nodejs server is running on ${this.host}:${this.port}`)
       });
   }
}
const app = new Server();
app.runServer(); // Run The Server Class
```

**The Socket configurations**

```
'use strict';
const axios = require('axios').default;
const {uuid} = require('uuidv4');

class Socket {
    constructor(socket) {
        this.io = socket;
    }

    //===================================================================
    ioConfig() {
        this.io.use((socket, next) => {

            socket['id'] = 'user_' + socket.handshake.query.user_id;

            console.log(socket.id);
            next();
        });
    }

    //===================================================================
    SocketConnection() {
        this.ioConfig();

        this.io.on('connection', (socket) => {

            //Location functions
            this.response_location(socket);

            //Alert functions
            this.response_alert(socket);

            // Disconnect function
            this.socket_disconnect(socket);
        });

    }    

    //===================================================================
    //Location functions
    response_location(socket) {
        socket.on('send_location', (data_object) => {
            var location_data = JSON.parse(data_object);

            async function saveLocation() {
                try {
                    const config = {
                        method: 'post',
                        url: 'http://' + process.env.LARAVEL_HOST + ':' + process.env.LARAVEL_PORT + '/api/employee/profile/update-location',
                        data: {
                            EmpId: location_data.user_id,
                            lat: location_data.lat,
                            lng: location_data.lng,
                            alt: location_data.alt,
                            speed: location_data.speed,
                            bearing_heading: location_data.bearing
                        },
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'x-auth-token': 'fb3813ef336d084750cfaf4d03c008ee',
                            'x-lang-code': 'en-us',
                            'x-user-type': '0',
                        },
                    };
                    let res = await axios(config);
                    console.log('=================saved location==============');
                    console.log(res.data);
                    console.log('=================saved location==============');

                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }

            }

            var added_location = saveLocation();

            if (added_location) {
                this.io.emit('get_location',  JSON.stringify({
                    user_id: location_data.user_id,
                    lat: location_data.lat,
                    lng: location_data.lng,
                    alt: location_data.alt,
                    speed: location_data.speed,
                    bearing: location_data.bearing
                }));
            }

        });
    }

    //===================================================================
    //Alert functions
    response_alert(socket) {
        socket.on('send_alert', (data_object) => {
            var alert_data = JSON.parse(data_object);

            async function saveAlert() {
                try {
                    const config = {
                        method: 'post',
                        url: 'http://' + process.env.LARAVEL_HOST + ':' + process.env.LARAVEL_PORT + '/api/employee/alerts/create',
                        data: {
                            type: alert_data.type,
                            lat: alert_data.lat,
                            lng: alert_data.lng,
                            alt: alert_data.alt,
                            acceleration: alert_data.acceleration,
                            speed: alert_data.speed,
                            time: alert_data.time,
                            idle_time: alert_data.idle_time,
                        },
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'x-auth-token': 'fb3813ef336d084750cfaf4d03c008ee',
                            'x-lang-code': 'en-us',
                            'x-user-type': '0',
                        },
                    };
                    let res = await axios(config);
                    console.log('=================saved alert==============');
                    console.log(res.data);
                    console.log('=================saved alert==============');
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }

            }

            var added_alert = saveAlert();

            if (added_alert) {
                this.io.emit('get_alert',  JSON.stringify({
                    type: alert_data.type,
                    lat: alert_data.lat,
                    lng: alert_data.lng,
                    alt: alert_data.alt,
                    acceleration: alert_data.acceleration,
                    speed: alert_data.speed,
                    time: alert_data.time,
                    idle_time: alert_data.idle_time,
                }));
            }

        });
    }

    // Socket disconnection
    socket_disconnect(socket) {
        socket.on('disconnect', (data) => {
            socket.disconnect();
            var index = this.online_users.indexOf(socket.id);
        })
    }
}
module.exports = Socket;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are providing the same user_id then your connection object is overriding in:

```
socket['id'] = 'user_' + socket.handshake.query.user_id;
```

Try to get them uique identifires.
For example, you can concat user_id and timestamp for the same users.

Comment: Good, you're Welcome!